# Eclipse CDT Luna untracked headers

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have an Eclipse C++ project generated from CMake. The project is tested and successfully compiled. But it still has strange unresolved symbols from the project itself.

Example:

```
// File source/Foo.hpp
#include "Bar.hpp" // file source/Bar.hpp
#include "Bas.hpp" // file source/Bas.hpp

class Foo {
   Bar _bar;
   Bas _bas; // unresolved name 'Bas'
};
```

Both Bar and Bas are included successfully. But only Bas is unresolved. Both Bar and Bas don't have any errors from Eclipse. Moreover, the project is pretty big, and a lot of files and dependencies are resolved. But there are a few like Bar, which are not different from others resolved files/classes. Any suggestions? Is it just Eclipse Parser is broken or lagging?

I noticed that headers which provide unresolved types are not added to Indexer, because when I refactore the project these headers are not change. Why CDT Indexer can ignore some header?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure “Preferences > C/C++ > Indexer > Allow heuristic resolutions of includes” is unchecked.